# Kubernetes pods keep crashing. With same docker image I built the docker container which is running fine

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have just started working on kubernetes.

My pod spec file

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "test-cfg",
    "labels": {
      "app": "swelite"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "config-agent",
        "image": "img1",
        "command": [
          "/etc/init.d/docker-init"
        ],
        "imagePullPolicy": "Never"
      },
      {
        "name": "other-proc",
        "image": "img2",
        "command": [
          "/etc/init.d/docker-init"
        ],
        "imagePullPolicy": "Never"
      }
   ]
  }
}
```

I have created two docker containers with img1 and img2 and they are running fine
When I try to create pod with containers using these two images, it keeps on crashing

I get this in the description of containers in pod

```
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
```

I suspect some issue with pod specs file because image is working if I bringup one docker container manually.

I don't get any useful information in logs as well. The log looks fine.

kubectl describe output

```
[root@node1 abs]# kubectl describe pod test-cfg
Name:         test-cfg
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         node1/10.0.0.30
Start Time:   Wed, 06 May 2020 12:04:12 +0000
Labels:       app=swelite
Annotations:  k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/network-status:
                [{
                    "name": "cni0",
                    "ips": [
                        "10.233.90.8"
                    ],
                    "default": true,
                    "dns": {}
                }]
              k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks-status:
                [{
                    "name": "cni0",
                    "ips": [
                        "10.233.90.8"
                    ],
                    "default": true,
                    "dns": {}
                }]
              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"swelite"},"name":"test-cfg","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"...
Status:       Running
IP:           10.233.90.8
IPs:
  IP:  10.233.90.8
Containers:
  config-agent:
    Container ID:  docker://dbd3ddf4c9f65fb0c97c30af3ab8e85da660e242b774be99f89e22b530a174e9
    Image:         img1
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:5eaaa7ee097877cb8b1628ed79f281006f01f39d8a30605d52dc40be5ae2da9f
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /etc/init.d/docker-init
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 06 May 2020 12:10:47 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 06 May 2020 12:11:30 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-648ql (ro)
  other-proc:
    Container ID:  docker://a6d4b63920b75e39fdbca37558cbbab23057d16fdb781144e51898f46b173aae
    Image:         img2
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:a33a6a51fb7a4398881c9ed0d201f03c490bb29581f7cb1c857edbd6cb7a5d48
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /etc/init.d/docker-init
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 06 May 2020 12:10:48 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 06 May 2020 12:11:31 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-648ql (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-648ql:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-648ql
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>              default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test-cfg to node1
  Normal   Pulled     6m19s (x3 over 8m)     kubelet, node1     Container image "img1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    6m19s (x3 over 8m)     kubelet, node1     Created container config-agent
  Normal   Started    6m18s (x3 over 8m)     kubelet, node1     Started container config-agent
  Normal   Pulled     6m18s (x3 over 8m)     kubelet, node1     Container image "img2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    6m18s (x3 over 7m59s)  kubelet, node1     Created container other-proc
  Normal   Started    6m17s (x3 over 7m59s)  kubelet, node1     Started container other-proc
  Warning  BackOff    5m34s (x3 over 6m31s)  kubelet, node1     Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  BackOff    3m (x10 over 6m31s)    kubelet, node1     Back-off restarting failed container
```

I think this maybe occuring because my main process in the docker-init script doesn't start
What I am trying to understand here is as to what difference is affecting pod containers but not docker container
Something to do with resource utilization?

Comment: `The log looks fine.` - then your logging might not be accurate. Do `kubectl describe ...` on problematic pods and share result

Comment: In the log, I get the exact same output which I get when i bringup the docker container.
If the docker container comes up fine then shouldn't the pod container come up fine too?

Comment: Not necessarily. There might be resource pressure or other problem in pod spec

Comment: Added the kubectl describe  output

Comment: Why two containers in the same pod?  Have you checked both containers' log outputs?  Do equivalent `docker run` commands outside Kubernetes work (and do the containers keep running, or exit immediately)?

Comment: My use case is to run multiple containers n one pod
I have checked both container log output, I didnt see any error.
I did do kubectl exec on the container
The containers didn't immediately exit but the script docker-init starts some process which isn't running 
I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at `/etc/init.d/docker-init` which seems to be terminating. Maybe it requires tty to keep running?

Comment: But the same script is running on the docker container
The issue is application itself restarting so the main process stops.

Comment: How exactly do you run containers from those images on plain docker ?

Comment: I use
 docker run -it --name <cont1> img1 /etc/init.d/docker-init
docker run -it --name <cont2> img2 /etc/init.d/docker-init

Answer (score 0):

After adding long sleep to my docker-init script, the script doesn't exit
and my containers don't restart.